# Android Studio: How to create quick clones or copies of current project

Tags: android, version-control, copy, clone, android-studio

Android Studio June 27th build
on Ubuntu 13

I'm having trouble understanding how to clone a project in Android Studio.  I'd like to take Project01 and copy it to a new Project02 and make updates/test/stablize and copy that to Project03 and continue.

I'm looking for options such as while in Project01 I'd just 'save as' Project02 and then open Project02 and continue.

I've read about the template and I've built templates but I'm unable to find where I can apply the templates when using the quick start 'new project' option.  Or how to apply the templates on a new project I've just created.

Comment: I think you can just copy the directory

Answer (score 5):

You could make a copy of the project directory outside of Android Studio and then import that copy as a new project in Android Studio. If you're looking to backup your code at regular intervals, though, you might be better served by using a version control system such as [Git](http://git-scm.com/).